# How To Customize ASP.NET Chart Using A Theme File

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-4, charts, mschart

i want to create a line Chart, where at the x-axis are the dates and on the y-axis there are the positions green(at the position of 0), yellow (1) and red (2).

How can i achieve this?

At the moment there are just the numbers.
I tried it with XML, but i dont know much about it and its a little bit confusing. Can i access the single elements of the y-axis with this and convert them to text?
Can i somehow implement an if else method within the Chart.AddSeries Method at axisLabel?

**Controller**

```
//XML
string t = @"
<Chart> 
  <ChartAreas> 
    <ChartArea Name=""Default"" _Template_=""All""> 
      <AxisY Interval=""1""> 
        <LabelStyle Font=""Verdana, 70px"" /> 
      </AxisY> 
    </ChartArea> 
  </ChartAreas> 
</Chart>";

var Date_min = OpenDate;
var Date_max = DateTime.Today;

var chart = new Chart(width: 300, height: 200, theme: t)
           .AddSeries(
                      chartType: "line",
                      name: "Temperature",
                      markerStep: 2,
                      xValue: Date_X,
                      yValues: Temperature_Y)       //0,1 or 2 for green, yellow and red                     
           .SetXAxis("Date", Date_min.ToOADate(), Date_max.ToOADate())
           .SetYAxis("Temperature", 0, 2.5)
           .GetBytes("png");
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

**Update**

I looked through the System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting Framework and did not find any additional function to solve my Problem.

I want to change the y-axis labels. Not the general Label of the y-axis but each position of it. There will be just three positions of the y-axis that have to be renamed to green, yellow and red instead of 0,1,2. 
Each Date of the x-axis will have a corresponding color.

[image: Example]

Comment: First, it is not clear what exactly you want to customize: Labels? DataPoints? Second, you're using `System.Web.Helpers`, which is a _dumbed down_ version of `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization`. You may want to switch to the latter depending on exactly what you want to customize.

Comment: You can create custom labels as you're describing using `System.Web.Helpers` and also customize the color of an entire series of points, but not the color of each individual point. For that you'd need `DataVisualization`.

Comment: If you can, post a picture of what you want to do.

Comment: But how is it possible to  to create custom labels? I hope the picture will help you, to understand the problem.

Comment: Please see my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this **theme** file (or string) to create a custom axis label:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
 <Chart> 
  <ChartAreas> 
    <ChartArea Name="Default" _Template_="All"> 
      <AxisY>
        <CustomLabels>
          <CustomLabel Text="GREEN (0 - 1)" ToPosition="1" />
          <CustomLabel FromPosition="1" Text="YELLOW (1 - 2)" ToPosition="2" />
          <CustomLabel FromPosition="2" Text="RED (2 - 3)" ToPosition="3" />
        </CustomLabels>
      </AxisY> 
    </ChartArea>
  </ChartAreas>
   <Series>
     <Series Name="Temperature" BorderWidth="3" >
     </Series>
   </Series>
   <Legends>
     <Legend Alignment="Center" Docking="Top" Name="Temperature">
     </Legend>
   </Legends>
 </Chart>
```

Controller.cs:

```
var Date_min = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-4);
var Date_max = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

        var chart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400, themePath: "XMLFile1.xml")
                   .AddSeries(
                              chartType: "line",
                              name: "Temperature",
                              xValue: new DateTime[] { DateTime.Now.AddDays(-4), DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3), DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2), DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1), DateTime.Now },
                              yValues: new int[] { 2, 1, 2, 2, 1 })       //0,1 or 2 for green, yellow and red                     
                   .SetXAxis("Date", Date_min.ToOADate(), Date_max.ToOADate())
                   .SetYAxis("Temperature", 0, 3.0)
                   .Save("~/Image/MyChart.png", "png");
```

[image]