# Specify data type in the ASP.NET MVC Razor Chart control

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, charts

I'm trying to use the "native" Chart control in ASP.NET.

The problem is, that I can't figure out how to specify the data type of the X axis.

The documentation for the Chart control is very limited.

```
var myChart = new Chart(2000, 600).AddTitle("Licenses")
.AddSeries(
name: "License usage",
xValue: licenseDates,
yValues: licenseCount);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have Model class like :

```
public class User
{
   public int Id { get; set; } 
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Age  { get; set; }
}
```

and you can get date like :

```
var users= _dbContext.Users.ToList()
```

Then :

```
var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
    .AddTitle("User Chart")
    .AddSeries(
         name: "User",
         xValue: users.select(u=>u.Name).ToArray(),
         yValues: users.select(u=>u.Age).ToArray()
        )
    .Write();
```

OR

```
var myChart = new Chart(2000, 600)
.AddTitle("Licenses")
.AddSeries(
    name: "User Chart",
    xValue: users, xField: "Name",
    yValues: users, yFields: "Age"
  );
```

you can get more information from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/data/7-displaying-data-in-a-chart) link.

Comment: The X-axis in my chart should contain a number of dates (DateTime). And the Y-axis specifies an integer for each of the dates. I'm trying to specify, that the X-axis is a date. By default the chart sees it as a string.

Comment: @ChristianTang you can use `SetXAxis` . you can flow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41174245/chart-helper-in-asp-net-display-datetime OR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38169328/how-to-customize-asp-net-chart-using-a-theme-file

Comment: Thanks. That was very helpful